# On idempotent elements that are contained in center of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $e$ and $f$ be idempotent elements of a ring $R$. Assume that $e,f$ are contained in center of $R$. Show that $Re=Rf$ if and only if $e=f$

Help me a hint to prove it.

Thank in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $r\in R$, we have $r\in Re$ if and only if $re=r$.

Indeed $re=r$ implies $r=re\in Re$; conversely, if $r\in Re$, then $r=xe$ for some $x$, and so $re=xee=xe=r$.

From $Re=Rf$ we get $f\in Re$, so $f=fe$. For the same reason $e=ef$. But since $e$ and $f$ commute, we have $e=f$.

Comment: How should we prove the converse?

Comment: @user109584 If $e=f$ it's *obvious* that $Re=Rf$, isn't it?

Comment: Ehm, of course. Thank you for your support

Answer (score 1):

HINT : show that the sum and product of $R$ induce a sum and product on $Re$. What can you say about $e\in Re$ with respect to multiplication?

Comment: Can you explain more precisely?

Comment: @user109584 Here's how I would say this hint in my own words. The first sentence would say instead "Notice that $eR$ is a subring of $R$! What is special about $e$ in this ring?" After you see this, then you would notice why, in the rings $eR$ and $fR$, which are equal, you must have $e=f$.

Comment: I don't see what motivated the downvote ^^

Comment: Neither do I! Strange...